# Issue with creating Cordova IOS build cache in CICD

Tags: ios, cordova, cocoapods

When creating the mobile artifact of IOS, I'm running:

```bash
npx cordova platform add ios 
npx cordova build
```

The build takes a long time for each run, and I started looking into ways to make it faster without any success.

To make the build faster, I started to look into caching the cocapods with GitHub Actions Cache. When running platform add ios, the cordova also creates:

- platforms/ios folder
- multiples files inside with Podfile, Podfile.lock, and Pods folder.

The issue starts when caching the Pods folder and restoring it into `platforms/ios/`. By default, when running the platform add command and the folder already exist (even with one txt file), the command returns the following output without adding all other relevant files:

```bash
Platform ios already added.
```

I thought about caching all the folders of platform IOS before running cordova build and the plugin folder, but I am unsure if it can cause issues down the road.
Additionally, I don't see any best practices or suggestions for the cordova cli cache.

How can I solve the cocapods issue, or what is the best way to make the pipeline run faster?